# Link/button is going off of the box i made for it

Tags: html, css

I made a link/button named Friends and when I re-size my window it goes out of the box I made for it. I have tried adding margins and padding but that didn't help me. Every thing I do still makes it go out of the box.

[image]

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}

.Forum-Block {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5%;
    left: 10%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 140%;
    margin: 5%;
    background-color: #888888;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: orange;
}
.Top-Bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 6%;
    background-color: black;    
}
.welcome-msg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 2%;
}
.friends-box {
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
    left: 90%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
.friends-box:hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 90%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #262626;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.friends-box {
        position: relative;
        top: 0%;
        right:2%;
        width: 15%;
        height: 100%;
        color: white;
        font-size:100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.friends-box:hover {

    background-color: #262626;
}
```

You should work to a grid as well - make the `.welcome-msg{width:75%;left:0;}` and the `.friend-box{width:25%;right:0}`

Wrap the text with tags, Welcome in H1, h2, or h4, and the friends in a p tag maybe and add padding to that instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just added floats and removed the position:absolute and position:relative... I also set the height of the Top-Bar to auto so that it takes the height of the content inside. I changed the background colors so you can see what is happening. Hope this helps!

```css
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: black;
    }
    .Forum-Block {
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 5%;
        left: 10%;
        top: 0%;
        width: 70%;
        height: 140%;
        margin: 5%;
        background-color: #888888;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: medium;
        border-color: orange;
    }
    .Top-Bar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8%;
        left: 5%;
        width: 90%;
        height:auto;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .welcome-msg {
        float:left;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding:10px;
      background: red;
    }
    .friends-box {
        float:right;
        color: white;
        background-color: green;
        padding:10px;
    }
    .friends-box:hover {
        background-color: #262626;
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<div class="Forum-Block">
    <div class="Top-Bar">
        <div class="welcome-msg">Hello, Admin</div>
        <div class="friends-box">Friends</div>
    </div>
</div>
```